# New line and COUNTIF function for VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function, countif

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of '1' in column (W_1).
I used the following code on VBA (a part of the entire code - will add more if needed). The data is also part of a table.

```
Private Sub Macro()

LastRow = x.Sheets("W_10").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim NewRow As Integer
NewRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
NewRow = LastRow + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(NewRow, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=countif(@[W_1],1)"

End Sub
```

I keep getting the following error

> error 104 - Application or object-defined error

Can anybody let me know where I'm going wrong please?
I've used a similar formula for another case before and was working fine.

Comment: What data type is the 1?  will it just be 1 or include 1?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it. It is just '1's and '0's - general datatype

Comment: If you are pasting a formula outside of a table don't you have to provide the name of the table along with the name of the table column?

Comment: We had tried that too.. tablename[column] , @tablename[column], tablename @[column] and tablename.[column]

Comment: Use .Formula, not .FormulaR1C1 and include the table name in the column reference

Comment: Jeeped - Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly (but it changes the table header from 'W_1' to '0' when we use 'NewRow' in the formula. hence we changed it to the row number and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Use .Formula, not .FormulaR1C1 and include the table name in the column reference

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqew()
    Dim NewRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        NewRow = 13
        .Cells(NewRow, 2).Formula = "=countif(Table1[W_1], 1)"
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, we understood one of our mistakes. But, I won't know for sure of the number of the row (we plan on updating the source file periodically, hence the number of rows keeps changing). And hence, I want to add a new row at the end of the table and insert the formula there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your sample data to test this, but I edited your code to use some more explicit references, which may take away your error...

```
Private Sub Macro()

Dim x As ActiveWorkbook
Dim LastRow As Integer

LastRow = x.Sheets("W_10").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim NewRow As Integer
NewRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
NewRow = LastRow + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(NewRow, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf([W_1], 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FindingLastRow()

'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Update")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  sht.Cells(LastRow + 2, 2).Formula = "=countif(Resume[W_1],1)"

End Sub
```

This one works good luck